# Lifetime of JSP created Objects

Tags: java, jsp, jboss

I am playing around with JBoss at the moment, creating a few applications, and I have a quick query.

If I am passing off execution problems and storing variables in class' kept elsewhere in the Application, will those changes stay present until JBoss is shutdown/restarted, or is there an internal garbage collection process that will reset these after a time?

Answer (score 0):

They should not get collected by garbage collection but this is not a good design.

1. You'll lose stored data if the application/server crushes
2. You risk memory leak
3. You have to be careful with thread safety.

What is usually stored in the application context is the static reference variables and singletons (e.g. if you use Spring framework, but this is another topic altogether). Almoust  everything else should NOT be stored in application context.

Comment: can you elaborate on why this is not a good design? sorry, i wasnt really making myself clear initially. i am storing data in static variables. this is so i can have shared data between many different connections and sessions

Comment: It is good idea only if data is not going to change. If it will, the other reasons this is not a good design:

Comment: Nah, just a registry for information on other threads. Once its created, its there till its deleted